# Use value from other row in case value is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3b77639f87e467f518378454bed0d844)**

```
CREATE TABLE Purchasing (
    id int primary key,
    event_type VARCHAR(255),
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    date_ordered VARCHAR(255),
    date_stored VARCHAR(255),
    quantity_ordered VARCHAR(255),
    quantity_stored VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Purchasing
(id, event_type, campaign, 
date_ordered, date_stored,
quantity_ordered, quantity_stored
)
VALUES 
("1", "ordered", "C001", "2019-01-17", NULL, "320", NULL),
("2", "ordered", "C002", "2019-03-12", NULL, "180", NULL),
("3", "ordered", "C003", "2019-05-08", NULL, "450", NULL),
("4", "ordered", "C004", "2019-08-20", NULL, "630", NULL),
("5", "stored", "C001", NULL, "2019-01-25", NULL, NULL),
("6", "stored", "C002", NULL, "2019-04-09", NULL, NULL);
```

In order to get all the campaigns with `event_type = stored` I run this query:

```
SELECT
campaign,
date_stored,
quantity_stored,
quantity_ordered
FROM Purchasing
WHERE event_type = "stored"
```

My issue is now that in the `event_type` `stored` there is no `quantity_stored`. 
In this case I want that the `quantity` of the `event_type` `ordered` is used. 
The expected result is:

```
campaign    date_stored      quantity
C001        2019-01-25          320
C002        2019-04-09          180
```

I tried to go with something like this but could not make it work:

```
SELECT
campaign,
date_stored,

  CASE(
  WHEN quantity_stored IS NULL THEN quantity_ordered 
  ELSE quantity_stored END) AS quantity

FROM Purchasing
WHERE event_type = "stored"
```

Comment: For each "stored" row, there's exactly 1 "ordered" row with the same campaign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.campaign, 
       t2.date_stored,
       COALESCE(t2.quantity_stored, t1.quantity_ordered) quantity
FROM Purchasing t1
JOIN Purchasing t2 ON t1.campaign = t2.campaign 
WHERE t1.event_type = 'ordered'
  AND t2.event_type = 'stored';
```

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1fd1d46f1178d115a780a8c066c4c7d0)**

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1fd1d46f1178d115a780a8c066c4c7d0

Comment: I added to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like

```
SELECT
p1.campaign,
p1.date_stored,

  CASE
  WHEN p2.quantity_stored IS NULL THEN p2.quantity_ordered 
  ELSE p2.quantity_stored END AS quantity



FROM Purchasing p1 join  Purchasing p2 on p1.campaign = p2.campaign and p1.event_type="stored"
and p2.event_type = "ordered"
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7054fadcc7797f5e46b4f201f0434f1d)

But why you store ordered and stored quantitiy in every record? Souldn't event type "stored" store the stored_quantity and the ordered event type the ordered quantity?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per campaign, you could use aggregation:

```
SELECT campaign,
       MAX(CASE WHEN event_type = 'stored' THEN date_stored END) as date_stored,
       COALESCE( SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 'stored' THEN quantity_stored END),
                 SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 'ordered' THEN quantity_ordered END)
               ) as quantity
FROM Purchasing
GROUP BY campaign
 HAVING quantity IS NOT NULL;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75bab3abcf2feced94b4f0c91575751e) is a db<>fiddle.

Your data model is quite strange, though.  Why do you have both an `event_type` and two quantity columns?  You should just have a single `quantity`, with the event type distinguishing between "ordered" and "stored".

Comment: I tried your solution but the quantity is NULL https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a96e177c698bc7ad91e841dfd8edec8e

Comment: @Michi . . . Thank you for setting up the fiddle.  It is just a question of taking the ordered quantity from the "ordered" rows.  As I say in the answer, this is a strange data model having two quantities, one which always seems to be `NULL`.